# HTML5/Javascript searching for existence of files in local directory

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, filesystems, fileapi

I'm trying to allow a web application to check for the existence of files in a user's local directory (the searches will repeat in the background).

I've researched this a good amount and found that one of the only ways that it seems to be possible is with the fileSystem API, which is only available in Chrome. The main issue with that is that the web app will primarily be running on Internet Explorer (if not exclusively).

Are there any ways to implement this functionality with HTML5/JS?

Thanks

Comment: yeah, that's just not going to happen I'm afraid..  You can definitely have a user pick a file to expose to you, but you're not going to be able to scan their directory willie-nillie

Comment: Is there a way to hardcode a file/directory path, and then prompt the user to allow looking in that directory?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure you can't, it's all up to the user.

Comment: Hm... in that case, could I ask the user for a directory path? Or would I really need to force them to choose every file to interact with...

Comment: They can't give you a path and let you go to town either I'm afraid.. they'll have to tell you each file individually (or select multiple at a time)

Comment: This page goes through pretty much everything you can do with the html5 file api.. unfortunately (for the dev, fortunately for users) the user has to hand off the files http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Ok, I figured that was the case (I had already read up on the file API some). Thanks for the answer!